# Parsing an NSObject into NSMutable array for UITextview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a code set below that I can quite get the syntax right for.

I'm trying to figure out how to connect the APIItem2 NSObject to the self.itemAPI pieces.

if I try and print the APIItem2.title property it says it's not part of the NSObject, but it definitely is.

Here is the whole piece of code.  I can provide any other files needed too.

```
#import "BDChangeApproveController.h"
#import "BDItemChangeDetailAPI.h"

@interface BDChangeApproveController () <NSURLSessionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSObject *APIItem2;

@end


@implementation BDChangeApproveController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void)refreshTextView
{
// set your text view with the api item here

NSLog(self.itemAPI.title,
      self.itemAPI.plannedStart,
      self.itemAPI.subcategory,
      self.itemAPI.service,
      self.itemAPI.associatedCi,
      self.itemAPI.environment,
      self.itemAPI.assignmentGroup,
      self.itemAPI.initiator,
      self.itemAPI.coordinator,
      self.itemAPI.riskLevel,
      self.itemAPI.performingGroup,
      self.itemAPI.implementationPlan,
      self.itemAPI.status,
      self.itemAPI.recoveryScope);


self.title = @"Action";
self.coNumberLabel.text = self.itemAPI.changeOrder;


NSMutableString *coDetailsText = [NSMutableString string];
coDetailsText =
[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Review Change Order details bellow\n====================\n%@ \n================== \nPlanned Start %@\n==================\nSubcategory: %@\n==================\nService: %@\n==================\nAssociated CIs: %@\n==================\nEnvironment CI: %@\n==================\nApproval Group: %@\n==================\nInitiator : %@\n==================\nCoordinator : %@\n==================\nRisk Level : %@\n==================\nPerforming Group : %@\n==================\nImplementation Plan : %@\n==================\nStatus : %@\n==================\nRecovery Plan : %@\n==================\n",


 self.itemAPI.title,
 self.itemAPI.plannedStart,
 self.itemAPI.subcategory,
 self.itemAPI.service,
 self.itemAPI.associatedCi,
 self.itemAPI.environment,
 self.itemAPI.assignmentGroup,
 self.itemAPI.initiator,
 self.itemAPI.coordinator,
 self.itemAPI.riskLevel,
 self.itemAPI.performingGroup,
 self.itemAPI.implementationPlan,
 self.itemAPI.status,
 self.itemAPI.recoveryScope];

//NSLog(coDetailsText);

self.coDetailsTextView.text = coDetailsText;



NSLog(@"End of the call and fill");

}

- (void)fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail
{

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                         delegate:nil
                                    delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *requestString1 = @"http://url.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString1];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

     NSDictionary *jsonObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:0
                                                                   error:nil];
     //NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject1);
     self.APIItem2 = jsonObject1[@"CoDetail"];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.APIItem2);






     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshTextView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

 }];

[dataTask resume];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail];
//self.recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.recipe.image];

NSLog(@"End of ViewDidLoad");

 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Comment: Why are you using an NSObject?  a JSON serialiser will return an NSArray or NSDictionary depending on the JSON it is parsing.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that last night.  I've changed it to NSArray.